# Cummulative sum on date, sorted by state SQL

Tags: sql, time, sum, state, cumulative-sum

I have a table with dates and differents states.

| date | state |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-11 16:49:45.157 | State 0 |
| 2021-07-07 16:45:33.863 | State 1 |
| 2021-07-07 16:45:32.943 | State 2 |
| 2021-07-07 16:42:29.457 | State 2 |
| 2021-07-07 16:23:50.263 | State 3 |
| ... | ... |

```
select 
    [date], [state] 
from 
    tempo 
order by [date] desc
```

I would get the actual time spent in every states and I tried to use a while loop to count the time spent in each state but I don't know if it is efficient and possible.
I'm a beginner in SQL

| state | total time (hour:min:sec) |
| --- | --- |
| State 0 | X:X:X |
| State 1 | X:X:X |
| State 2 | X:X:X |
| State 3 | X:X:X |
| ... | ... |

I have no idea how I can get those cumulative time...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use  OVER, and ORDER BY CLAUSE

Comment: Is it guaranteed to exist distinct state values per each row, or some of them are repeated within the upcoming rows which are not currently displayed?

Comment: Time is incremental, so every row is garanteed to be different.

Comment: I tried something and it worked, but it's really not efficient...
- declare Sum variable as float for each state
- Read in a while loop each row and increment Sum variables according to the state with datediff() function
- Create new table with states and Sum variables